# OnTouchEvent in a MapItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

I have a MapView with a MapItemizedOverlay, like this :

```
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
itemizedOverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(drawable);

OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "", "");

itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);        
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

I want to know when the user touches the AndroiMarker, so I can show some info about that specific place. How do I do that ?

Tks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Implement `onTap()` in your `MapItemizedOverlay` class.

[Here is an example](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/).